# How to add content programmatically to a field collection that it's in an entity (build with eck)

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to save information into an entity build with [eck](http://drupal.org/project/eck), this entity has a field_collection with more fields.

I have take a look around internet, and I only find examples that works with node entity and user entity, but when I try to use the same code with my entity, it doesn't works.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$idform = 1;
$entity = entity_load('formulario',array($idform));
//dpm($entity);


$newfield_collection = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_form_field'));
$newfield_collection->setHostEntity('formulario',$entity);
$newfield_collection->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]='name3';
$newfield_collection->field_form_id[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['value']=3;
$newfield_collection->field_sff_name[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['value'] = 'value name 3';
$newfield_collection->field_field_id[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['value'] = '13434';
$newfield_collection->field_field_type[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['value'] = 'value type 3';
$newfield_collection->save(FALSE);

?>
```

And this is my error message:

> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type
>   formulario. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7633 of
>   /home/oscar/webapps/www/drupal/drupal7/includes/common.inc).

I have debuging the code and seems that the problem is with `setHostEntity` But I don't know if it's because I build the entity with eck module.

Thanks

Oskar

Comment: Please read [ask] and possible [faq] and accept some answers to your other questions.  You are not likely to get many useful answers with a big red 0% below your name.

Comment: No problem, I hope I didn't come across as obnoxious.  Some people may see the low acceptance rate and pass right by without answering, which means you won't get an answer - don't really want to have that happening :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that [entity_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7) returns an array, not the single entity. So you should do something like this :

```
$entities = entity_load('formulario',array($id));
$entity = end($entities);
```

and then the rest of your code ...

Comment: Of course I have devel enabled, I have a commented dpm function in the code, I'm going to check the entity_get_info(). Thanks

Comment: could it be that you have it deployed via a feature ?

Comment: search for ['entity keys']['bundle']

Comment: Hello mojzis, is not yet a feature. 
I have check the dpm and I find that the ['formulario']['entity keys']['bundle'] is "type".

The question is How I should have to call it: ::setHostEntity('type',$entity); ?

Comment: and if you dpm() the entity after you load it ? does it have the type property ?

Comment: If I make a dpm(entity_load('formulario')); it doesn't give nothing of information about the bundle.
entity_load('type') gives me an error about the name of the entity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6806/discussion-between-mojzis-and-oskar-calvo)

Comment: Thanks mojzis, I think that this can be a bug from eck, I'will ask in field collection module and eck module bugs track.

Comment: @OskarCalvo ... sorry it took me so long, i see the problem now :) entity_load doesnt return the entity, but an array ... i will change the reply

Answer (score 0):

Use [entity_load_single](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_load_single/7) instead of entity_load to load single value instead of array.

This will solve the error.